# Can the characteristic function of a Borel set be approached by a sequence of continuous function through a certain convergence in $L^\infty$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

Want to find $f_n$ a sequence of continuous functions, so that for all Borel regular measure $\mu$, we have

$\int f_n d\mu\rightarrow\int \chi_\Delta d\mu$, as $n$ goes to infinity, where $\Delta$ is a Borel set.

Comment: I don't think this is weak convergence, the dual of $L^{\infty}$ is *finitely* additive set functions, not just measures.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: And moreover, the dual of $L^\infty$ is only those finitely additive set functions which are absolutely continuous to your reference measure (which has not been specified).  I think this question needs to be clarified.

Comment: Similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2482042/forall-f-bounded-borel-functions-exists-f-n-continuous-s-t-forall-m/2482394#2482394

Comment: @Dap   yeah,  I agree with the use of Dirac measure.  So, we cannot talk about the convergence in all Borel measure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(EDITED)
Let $\Delta$ be the rationals in $[0,1]$.  If your condition is satisfied, in particular $f_n$ converges pointwise to $\chi_\Delta$.  Let $C_n = \{x \in [0,1]: \forall m > n, \;|f_n(x) - f_m(x)|\le 1/3\}$.  Then $C_n$ are closed and their union is $[0,1]$.  By the Baire category theorem some $C_n$ has nonempty interior.  But this is impossible since $f_n$ is continuous and both $\Delta$ and its complement are dense.

Comment: Of course, this raises just another question now: is it nevertheless true that the weak closure in $L^\infty$ of the set of continuous functions contains the characteristic functions of Borel sets? (The topology is not metrizable, so limits of sequences do not define the closure.)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen If by weak closure you mean $\sigma(L^\infty, (L^\infty)^*)$-closure then isn't this just equal to the norm closure? (Mazur's theorem.) Or is this the probabilist's notion of weak convergence?

Comment: @YemonChoi I'm a poor ignorant algebraist who's a bit lost in a twisty maze of "weak" topologies all alike, but I meant the one which seems to be implicit in the question, namely, the coarsest topology on the set of bounded Borel functions which makes $f \mapsto \int f\,d\mu$ continuous for every finite regular Borel measure. (I guess I shouldn't have written $L^\infty$.) Or, what I hope amounts to the same: what if we change the question slightly to allow converging (Moore-Smith) nets $f_\alpha$ rather than merely sequences $f_n$ of continuous functions?

Comment: If $\Delta$ is as suggested by Robert, then, again by one of the corollaries of Baire's theorem, $\chi_\Delta$ has a point of continuity (being Baire-$1$), which it doesn't. I think, Robert's $C_n$ are all empty (hence closed!), since $f_n$ is continuous; still the convergence assumption would force the union of the $C_n$ to be $[0,1]$. -- As for notation, it seems to me that the OP has defined his own ``weakish'' convergence different from weak convergence in Banach spaces.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I agree that this is not the "weak" topology defined by the dual of $L^\infty$ (it was probably a mistake of mine to even mention $L^\infty$, which is not in the question), but it is legitimate to ask about the topology defined (on the bounded Borel functions I guess) by the seminorms $f\mapsto\left|\int f\,d\mu\right|$ for finite regular Borel measures $\mu$, which seems to be [a kind of weak topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology_%28polar_topology%29), no? I'm seriously confused at this point, but I think this makes sense.

Comment: My apologies; the part of my previous comment that the $C_n$ must be empty was bare nonsense.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen: Actually, the most relevant point seems to be the one Nate makes above, in a very slightly different context. For a general (not necessarily ac) measure $\mu$, one can't even define $\int f\, d\mu$ as a functional on $L^{\infty}$ since the integral is now sensitive to changes of $f$ on a (Lebesgue) null set.

Comment: @Christian Remling  It's my fault.  I didn't ask it separately.  I just want to know whether it is possible to find a sequence of continuous functions approaching the characteristic function in any regular Borel measure. At the mean time, is such a convergence possible in $L^\infty$ in the weak sense?

Comment: @Robert Israel: Excuse me,  I don't see the contradiction between the continuity of the functions and the density of rationals.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Yes, it was a mistake of mine to even mention $L^\infty$ (it was not in the question). But if we consider, instead, all bounded Borel functions (with pointwise equality!), I think it makes sense to take the topology defined by the seminorms $f\mapsto\int f\,d\mu$ for all finite regular Borel measures $\mu$. The original question would then be: "can we find a sequence of continuous functions converging to a given $\chi_\Delta$ in this sense?", but one can also ask about their closure (or convergence of nets). (Maybe this is a stupid question.)

Comment: @Bruno Suppose $(a,b) \subset C_n$.  Thus for every $x \in (a,b)$, $|f_n(x) - \chi_\Delta(x)| = \lim_{m \to \infty} |f_n(x) - f_m(x) | \le 1/3$.  Thus $f_n(x) \ge 2/3$ if $x \in \Delta$, $f_n(x) \le 1/3$ if $x \notin \Delta$.  If $(a,b)$ contains a member of $\Delta$ and a member of its complement, this contradicts the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: @Robert Israel,  I see, and it's a nice proof.   You are actually proving the characteristic function of rationals is not the pointwise limit of continuous functions. Using in particular the Dirac measure, I now have a full answer for my question.